# Run two python function in parallel does not produce result

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have two python function which I want to run in parallel. I don't want sub_task function to wait for main_task function.

```
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep,time

def main_task():
    while True:
        sleep(2)
        print('main task running')
    
def sub_task():
    while True:
        sleep(5)
        print('sub task running')
```

When I used thread this way, I can see output

```
q=Thread(target = main_task).start() 
s=Thread(target = sub_task).start()
```

But when I used Process this way, I cannot see ouput

```
q=Process(target = main_task).start() 
s=Process(target = sub_task).start()
```

So what is wrong with the implementation.

Comment: add q.join() and s.join() at end

Comment: `Thread.start` and `Process.start` return `None`. You need to do `q = Process(target = main_task)` then `q.start()` if you want to use the process object. Same with threads.

Comment: I changed it to this `q=Process(target = main_task)`
`s=Process(target = sub_task).start()`
`q.start() `
`s.start() `
`q.join()`
`s.join()`

But still no result

Comment: Because these processes are not marked "daemon", the parent process should do a join on them, effectively blocking the parent until the subprocesses terminate. It works for me in the console on linux. If you are running in an IDE, it could be that its faked stdout in the parent but the subprocess stdouts are going to bascially `/dev/null`. So, what operating system and how are you running the script?

Comment: yes it runs in console. but its run main_task, then wait for sub_task, then main_task and sub_task.... but I don't want main_task to wait for sub_task, as time delay in main_task is less, it should be executed more than sub_task